# Why does StratifiedShuffleSplit return training/testing indices of full dataset when calling next()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to take a stratified sub-sample of my data, since the dataset is rather large (+- 100k images).
I was trying to be clever by using the `StratifiedShuffleSplit` class of scikit-learn. [The documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) provides me the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Which gives the following output (The indices of respective Train/test splits):

```
TRAIN: [5 2 3] TEST: [4 1 0]
TRAIN: [5 1 4] TEST: [0 2 3]
TRAIN: [5 0 2] TEST: [4 3 1]
TRAIN: [4 1 0] TEST: [2 3 5]
TRAIN: [0 5 1] TEST: [3 4 2]
```

Based on the above, and since the type of StratifiedShuffleSplit is a generator, I expected the following code (with a call to `next()` would provide me with *one* of the created splits.

```
sss = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=0) 
train_index, test_index = next(sss.split(X, y)) #I expected this call to next would give me the indices of ONE of the (in this case 10) splits                         
print(type(sss.split(X,y)))                         #Type is generator
```

However, when I check the len() afterwards, I see that I actually get the full dataset back! Can somebody explain me why this happens, and how I can achieve my goal of taking a Stratified sub-sample?

```
y_complete = np.concatenate((y[train_index], y[test_index]))            
X_complete = np.concatenate((X[train_index], X[test_index]))             
print(len(y_complete), len(X_complete)) #Gives me full length of dataset (So 99289 instead of expected 9920)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour that you are seeing in the example that you have created. If you only look at `train_index` and `test_index` separately, then you will se that there are mutually exclusive set of indices inside them. However, if you look at the concatenated set of indices inside `train_index + test_index`, **the combined set of indices will be the full dataset itself.**   See the below code for more clarity:

```
ss = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=0)
split_gen = sss.split(X, y) # Store this generator in a variable 
train_index, test_index = next(split_gen)                         
print(type(sss.split(X,y)))

print("Length of Training split is {}".format(len(y[train_index])))
print("Indices are {}".format(train_index))
print("Actual data at those indices is {}".format(y[train_index]))

# Output : 
# Length of Training split is 3
# Indices are [5 2 3]
# Actual data at those indices is [1 0 1]
```

Notice here how `train_index` contains only 3 indices and not the complete dataset itself. Similar behaviour can be seen for `test_index`:

```
print("Length of Test split is {}".format(len(y[test_index])))
print("Indices are {}".format(test_index))
print("Actual data at those indices is {}".format(y[test_index]))

# Output : 
# Length of Test split is 3
# Indices are [4 1 0]
# Actual data at those indices is [1 0 0]
```

You can see here that `[5 2 3]` and `[4 1 0]` are mutually exclusive, but combine to form the full dataset, which is happening when you are using `np.concatenate` above.

To get the next split, you use `next` on the generator object:

```
train_index, test_index = next(split_gen)
print("Length of Set 2 Training split is {}".format(len(y[train_index])))
print("Indices are {}".format(train_index))
print("Actual data at those indices is {}".format(y[train_index]))

# Length of Set 2 Training split is 3
# Indices are [5 1 4]
# Actual data at those indices is [1 0 1]
```

Comment: Aahh, so if I understand correctly the StratifiedShuffleSplit doesn't create 10 splits of 1/10th of the data, but it creates 10 different, mutually exclusive splits of the full data?I think that's where I made a small thinking mistake.

Comment: MVP! Sometimes all it takes is somebody to point you to a thinking mistake you made. This is why i love SO sometimes! TYVM